# Is tilde attribute selector much slower than class selector?

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

In a case like the following, is the performance impact significant?

html

```
<div class="6u 12u(xsmall)"></div>
```

css

```
[class~="6u"] { background-color: red }
/* instead of */
.\36 u { background-color: red }
```

The advantage is obviously readability.

Edit: I already proposed changing the classes to be eg `u6` and not require escaping, but I am asking in the meantime, since I can not change the markup at the moment.

Comment: Well if readability is what you want, then I would avoid class names starting with numbers (that then in turn require you to write less readable CSS selectors) - make that `u6` and `u12`, problem gone & solved.

Comment: I know that is optimal, but that's not possible yet. I added an edit.

Comment: Well unless the documents to be formatted are really huge (number of DOM element wise), the performance difference should be negligible.

Comment: I don't know, why don't you run a benchmark?